# Error ITMS-90046 when submitting .ipa from Phonegap Build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, phonegap-build, application-loader

I'm developing an app using Phonegap Build. I'm trying to submit the .ipa file to iTunes Connect using Application Loader.

I'm getting the following error:
[Screenshot error when submitting with Application Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6f46.png)

```
ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. 
Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that
are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key
'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in Payload/GHLRooster.app/GHLRooster'
is not supported."
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: what does this command show "codesign -d --entitlements - GHLRooster.app" ?

Comment: @MikeDemidov Already found the problem (as written below). Some setting was causing this error to show up in the Application Loader before submitting. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this error by logging in to the [Apple Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and unchecking the "Associated Domains" service in the App ID settings as shown in the screenshot below.

[Screenshot of App ID settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hph9Z.png)

This got me past this error and I could submit the app to iTunes Connect.